# How to use the printer with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

When I run my WebService in VisualStudio, it works correctly. Prints on the printer without problems using a dll.
When I publish to IIS, it doesn't print but it doesn't give any error, the page keeps loading.
I use two functions of this dll and only the one of the printing crashes.
I entered a user account in IIS and gave permission for it, but the problem remains. What can be done?

IIS log:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-01-27 21:13:34
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2021-01-27 21:13:34 ::1 GET /WebserviceHost/WebService1.asmx op=ImprimeNota 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/87.0.4280.141+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/WebserviceHost/WebService1.asmx 200 0 0 833
2021-01-27 21:14:16 ::1 GET /WebserviceHost/WebService1.asmx op=ImprimeNota 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/87.0.4280.141+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/WebserviceHost/WebService1.asmx 200 0 0 3
```

Comment: Anything in `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` or event viewer on IIS machine? How is the printer attached?

Comment: For how to use the printer in IIS you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/manage-connect-printers-use-web-browser